# Python based browser plug-in?

Tags: plugins, python-3.x

Is there any good browser plugin that has Python as its primary scripting language. It is ok even if it has very minimal graphical abilities like just taking inputs through HTML forms or parameters and rendering text as output.

One option is running Python on server side. But unfortunately, I am not allowed to install any Python server side framework.

**EDIT**
It seems that Silverlight can use IronPython as its language. But any other more cross platform solutions are still welcome.

Comment: You can run Python in the browser without additional plugins, using a JavaScript implementation of Python. See here: http://syntensity.com/static/python.html

Comment: Page not found for syntensity.com/static/python.html on 08 March 2021. Domain for sale.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the [PyXPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/pyxpcom) add-on to Firefox. It seems to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Page not found on 08 March 2021.